# Why are wxWindows and PangoCairo used together?

Tags: wxwidgets, pangocairo

I'm probably way out of the loop, but it seems weird to use a native look GUI library and then - if you're not using wxGTK - shoehorn in a text renderer from a *different* GUI library. What's the deal here?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Can you be more specific. Especially clarify "not using wxGTK" part. Are you talking about wxQt? Or using wxGTK under Windows? Or maybe Wayland? Can you give a scenario you are asking about?

Comment: If you're using WX, why use a library from GTK, when WX is not necessarily GTK? It seems like using a Java TreeView in a Windows Forms program.

Comment: wx in Linux uses internally GTK and Pango-Cairo. In Windows and OSX OS-API functions are used. To be complete, you can also use wx with GTK in Windows. You don't need to use Pango & Cairo on your own, but you can if you wish so.

Comment: So using PangoCairo and WX requires having two different windowing tool kits running at once on non-Linux. Why do that just for text handling? Is Pango that great?

Comment: Well, there's also wxX11 which doesn't use GTK. But it's not as mature as wxGTK. When possible, wx calls only GTK commands, but for a few cases is better to use Pango directly (e.g. text measures). And wx is not just *text handling*.

Comment: Why do you say *"two different windowing tool kits running at once"*? Which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your point. Using GTK (and Pango Cairo) on Windows, by telling wxWidgets to use internally GTK seems duplicating window managers.

It's just a matter of taste. GTK in Windows does call Windows API to do windowing. But some users like the GTK-way for windows, menus, and other controls instead of the native Windows-way, and wxWidgets provides this feature (in addition, of course, of the native usage, keeping native look&feel).

Anyhow, GTK on Linux calls internaly X11 or Wayland for handling windows and menus. Do you also call this "duplicating"?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to stem from a mistaken assumption, so it's hard to answer it, let me rather explain how things really are instead:

Cairo-based `wxGraphicsContext` can be *optionally* used under MSW because this allows to produce exactly the same graphics output under all platforms, which can be important for some kinds of applications. However it is not used by default, you need to explicitly request it, and if you don't you'd be using GDI+ or Direct2D, both of which are perfectly native libraries.